# What kind of performance gain will I get from ditching Apache for NGINX?

Tags: performance, apache, webserver, nginx

What kind of performance gain will I get from ditching Apache for NGINX if I have a very low traffic web site (e.g. 1000 unique visitors a day, approx 5 requests/sec at highest load, and approx 50 MB of traffic per day since lots of photos are being displayed).

Specifically, what gains (if any) would I have for:

- Loading speed of the web site from the web user perspective
- Server load
- Concurrency

Again, this is for a low traffic web site and I'm running on a VPS.

Comment: @chaos, I've updated the original post to elaborate on the "low traffic" metric

Answer (score 3):

If you have such a low traffic, I am not sure you need to go through the troubles of changing your webserver : kind of looks like "premature optimisation" to me.

*Well, at least, if those 1,000 visitors don't visit too many pages, and don't all arrive at exactly the same time.*

You'd probably have way better gains for your users (and that's what matter !) by activating gzip compression for JS/CSS/HTML, and/or regrouping JS/CSS files into one instead of several, for instance.

About that, running [yslow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) on your webite, and following some of the advices it'll give you, will probably bring more speed to your users than changing server.

Just to make clear : I don't say that you shouldn't optimize your server -- but that, with such a low traffic, it might be more interesting to display pages faster ; at least, first.

Comment: Using YSLOW, my web site receive an A rating. Meaning, I already have gzip enabled, I minimize the # of JS/CSS files, etc.

Comment: Also, my web site is entirely HTML (no PHP/JSP/Python).  I'm simply curious to know if the NGINX works well for low traffic web sites as well.

Comment: Ouch ^^ Nicele done, so ! (I don't see that many sites that get an A ^^ )

Comment: Thanks. Seriously. I went to great lengths to achieve that A rating. I'm a little proud of it :)

Comment: You can be ^^ Even if it's probably "overkill", you probably can be kinda proud of it -- and I'm guessing it was fun ^^

Comment: So with that being said, any performance gain by going to NGINX?  My concern right now is that I load a lot of imagines from my site since it's a real estate web site showing pictures of all the homes. At times, it appears slow to load. Would moving to NGINX be of benefit or simply using a CDN for all the house photos?

Comment: I don't really know if / how much you'll gain ; I suppose no-one ever really did that kind of comparison is such low-load conditions... Still, I doubt that much time is spent on the "serving" part (Apache is quite fast, when it comes to serving static files) : the difference should **probably** not be that big ; maybe a couple milliseconds ? But I doubt end-user will perceive that ;; maybe a CDN would help, if you have users all arround the world, or they are "far" from your server... but it's another "maybe"...

Answer (score 1):

Is your Apache server taking too much CPU or RAM? I switched from Apache to Nginx to save memory, especially to serve static file: I seem to be using about 75% less memory with Nginx.

Like the other comment said, are you sure that Apache is the bottle neck? If you are not swapping, then you have enough memory. I don't think you will save any significant server side latency.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand correctly, what you're saying is that you don't believe NGINX will serve up my HTML web site quicker to the end user for them to notice a difference?

Comment: Right, from what you described, they won't see any difference. That said, I found using Nginx easier than Apache. If you think you will significantly increase your number of hits (so your server load), you can start switching now.